# CSS float property on an iframe, widely supported?

Tags: css, iframe

`<iframe id="dropdownlist" style="height:27px; float:right;" src="http://www.a.com/a.html"></iframe>`

Example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_align_css

I've never used this property for an iframe, only for pictures, and I do need to use it now. I tested on opera, chrome, firefox, safari and ie10 and it worked. I'm not really worried about much older browsers, but how supported is that property for iframes?
Or since its css, should it work the same (picture or iframe) regardless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any issues with floating an IFrame personally. If you want to be very sure then create a quick sample page (or use an [existing one](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_align_css)) and run it through [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/).

[image]

Comment: Thanks mike, will check that website!